# how to redirect the user to a page using if condition to validate the value he introduces in the form?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, ado.net

The application has a Register Page and when the user signs up it is important that the system identifies its type of profile in order to redirect his specific page.
There are two user profiles and two menus.
What I intend to do is the following: when the user who has 'CodPerfil = 1' clicks the enter button then the system directs to the 'MenuMoradores' page.
And when 'CodPerfil = 2' then the system directs to the 'MenuRecolhedores' page.
The application gets values ​​from the Web API and the 'CodPerfil' value corresponds to the value selected in the picker 'SelectedPerfil'.

**This is the ViewModel**
I tried this method that I called 'Validation()' to do the job but it doesn't work.

```
//This property is of type 'Int' which is linked to the item selected 
in the picker that needs to be validated to direct to the pages. This property only have two values: 'CodPerfil=1', 'Titulo=Morador' that is binded in the picker and 'CodPerfil=2', 'Titulo=Recolhedor'.

public int CodPerfil
        {
            get
            {
                return _codperfil;
            }
            set
            {
                _codperfil = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

public ICommand RegistarCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    var usuario = new UsuarioModel
                    {
                        Nome = Nome,
                        Senha = Senha,
                        Telefone = Telefone,
                        CodPerfil = SelectedPerfil.CodPerfil
                    };
                    await _apiServices.RegistoUsuarioAsync(usuario);
                    if (usuario.CodPerfil == 1)
                    {
                        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MenuMorador());
                    }
                    else if (usuario.CodPerfil == 2)
                    {
                        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MenuRecolhedor());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //
                    }
                });

            } 
        }
... 
//I hid the code for the other properties and the selected item
```

**RegisterPage.xaml**
I just put the most relevant code

```
            <Picker x:Name="PerfilPicker" Title="Selecione o seu Perfil" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Perfis}" 
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Titulo}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerfil}" />
                    Command="{Binding RegistarCommand}"/>
```

any help will be appreciated. thank you

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Do you get an error or exception?

Comment: I mean does not return any error ... the user is registered but is not directed to either page.

Comment: How are you getting access to the Navigation object from your VM?  Have you stepped through your logic in the debugger?

Comment: I declared a public INavigation Navigation {get; set; }

Comment: how can i examine my logic in the debugger?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/?view=vs-2019

Comment: That logic that I'm using doesn't seem very right. If you can give me tips on how I can apply this condition through an integer value that is read on the login or registration form by the application connected to the web API I would be grateful.

Comment: first, shouldn't you validate your data **before** you can your webservice?  And why is Validate() creating an empty `UsuarioModel` instead of using the one created by `RegistarCommand`?

Comment: I took note of your tip and changed it right now. I debugged and received a message: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not defined for an instance of an object.'

Comment: Without knowing what specifically you changed there is no way for me to help

Comment: I just put the if condition inside the 'Register Command' after the following statement: await _apiServices.RegistoUsuarioAsync (user); then I debugged and received NullReferenceException, even checking through the debugger that the 'CodPerfil' was filled with the value.

Comment: it is a lot more helpful to edit your question with the new code than to stuff it in a comment and expect anyone to make sense of it.  And again, you have basic C# error, use the debugger to chase it down.

Comment: I already edited the question. I've also done the debugging and I don't understand why this exception of the type NullReferenceException appears, because the data is being recorded.

Comment: the exception (or debugger) should show you which **specific line of code** causes the exception, and then you can use the debugger to figure out which object is null